# SQL Getting last date and values associated with description of value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two different tables, my first table contains the authorizations granted to other requests. It has the following columns:

#### Authorizations table

```
| authorization_date | role_id | request_id |
|--------------------|---------|------------|
| 2011-08-02         |    1    | 168        |
| 2011-08-10         |    2    | 168        |
| 2011-08-20         |    6    | 168        |
| 2011-08-03         |    2    | 169        |
| 2011-08-24         |    6    | 169        |
| 2011-08-05         |    3    | 170        |
| 2011-08-09         |    5    | 170        |
```

As you can see, different people have different roles and also can grant a certain level of authorization. The higher the role, the higher the request has been processed.
Now, what I want to do is I want to show the description associated to the role_id (which is in another table) and ONLY the last authorization. Since I have the date for it I already know which one is the latest one. However I don't know how to do this as I try to group my query by getting the maximum value of the date, when I link it to my second table containing only the description of the role_id, I get duplicates and I just can't think of a way to do this, I'm kind of new with queries & as I've been learning by myself I don't know many things. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried doing a MAX(request_date) and grouping it by the request_id, but it doesn't work when I try to do an inner join with my other table that contains the description of the role_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing a little here, but I think you want:

```
SELECT Authorizations.*, anotherTable.description
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX(authorization_date) AS max_date, request_id
    FROM Authorizations
    GROUP BY request_id
) last_auths
INNER JOIN Authorizations ON last_auths.max_date = Authorizations.authorization_date
    AND last_auths.request_id = Authorizations.request_id
INNER JOIN anotherTable ON anotherTable.role_id = Authorizations.role_id
```

The derived table will get the maximum authorization date for each request. Then you can join to get the role_id for that request and join again to get the description.

Comment: This is awesome, it definitely does what I need it to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.role_desc, a.role_id, MAX(a.authorization_date)
FROM Authorizations a
INNER JOIN Description d ON a.role_id = d.role_id
GROUP BY a.role_id, d.role_desc, d.role_id
```

Try this query and ensure you are getting the expected result.

Comment: I get this error when I try that 
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'd.role_desc' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.